# How to ensure the correct supply voltage when using a current mirror

Tags: transistors, current-mirror

I am trying to design a current mirror with a constant current source and 2 parallel LEDs (I have to connect the LEDs in parallel and cannot use a separate current source for each LED).

[image: Current mirror with parallel LEDs]

If each LED needs X volts, and Q1 will have 0.6-0.7V across the collector-emitter junction (one diode drop) then the supply will need to provide the LED voltage plus the 0.6-0.7V.

It was pointed out to me that the collector-emitter voltage of the transistors in the LED branches can vary between their saturation voltage and 0.6-0.7V meaning the voltage across the LEDs will also vary.

How to you ensure the voltage across the LEDs is exactly what the LEDs require?

Comment: You can't make the voltages **exactly** the same, and you don't want to. You want the **current** through the LEDs to be within an **acceptable range**. So what are you really trying to do, and what is your acceptable range for the three LED currents?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the LED currents should be around 500mA each. I understand there will be slight variations and one LED will not 'want' the same Vf and If. I would just like to know how to calculate what the correct supply voltage should be. Is VLED + 0.6-0.7V correct for the supply voltage?

Comment: You need a voltage source; the programming element (R1, Q1) will set the current at (Vs - 0.7) / R1. That current will be mirrored into Q2 and Q3 (within some tolerance) providing the collector - emitter voltages are within the compliance range of the mirror.

Comment: If you're starting with a **current source** in the first place (1.5A), then why do you need transistor **current sinks** at all? Each LED might require a small series resistor (about one ohm) to ensure they share current equally. Then reduce the current source to 1 A. Feeding a current source into a current sink is asking for trouble, just as adding two voltage sources in parallel is trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the collector of Q1 will be at 0.7V (\$V_{CE1} = 0.7V \$).

The collector-to-emitter voltage across Q2 (\$V_{CE2}\$) and Q3 (\$V_{CE3}\$) can vary from 0.1V upwards to any voltage, way beyond 0.7V if necessary, and permitted.

However, I think I'm confused, because the algebra doesn't "add up". I'll label some currents as follows: \$ I_1 \$ is the current in the left-most path, through R1 and Q1. \$ I_2 \$ and \$ I_2 \$ are the currents in the next two paths, in Q2 and Q3 respectively. \$ I_T \$ will be the current emerging from the source, and branching into those three paths.
$$I_T = I_1 + I_2 + I_3$$
We have also the current mirror trying to impose these conditions:

$$ I_2 = I_3 = I_1 $$

Now let's assume you've somehow set \$ I_1 \$, but due to component tolerances, you haven't done so very precisely. It ends up being 510mA. That poses a conflict:

$$ I_2 = I_3 = I_1 = 510mA $$
$$ I_T = I_1 + I_2 + I3 = 1530mA $$

This directly contradicts the condition that \$ I_T = 1500mA \$. Essentially, you can't choose \$ I_1 \$ and \$ I_T \$, and expect things to work out well. The easiest solution I can think of, to fix that particular dilemma, is to replace the 1.5A current source with a fixed voltage source, one whose voltage is greater than the largest voltage drop you expect across either of the LEDs. I suspect this is not an option, otherwise you would not have posted this question.

In real life, the system will of course settle into some equilibrium, but the very nature of the algebra tells me that this equilibrium is ambiguous.

I notice also that R1 passes the same current, and must drop approximately the same voltage, as the LEDs, and therefore dissipates the same power as the LEDs, which seems terribly wasteful to me.

In the spirit of the question, though, which boils down to "how can we allow Q2 (and Q3) to adjust the current through their loads, and produce exactly the right voltage across them for that current?", the answer is simple - give them "room to manoeuvre".

In other words, focusing on Q2 here, Q2's \$ V_{CE} \$ must be able to vary from 0.1V up to some arbitrarily higher voltage, in order to "take up" any excess voltage across its load that would cause the current through that load to exceed the "set" (required) value. We need to define the voltage at the top of the LED (shared by all the paths) - I'll call it \$ V_{TOP} \$. We also need to define the voltage across the load LED (the LED's "forward voltage") that will cause the expected current to pass. I will call this \$ V_F \$.

Imagine the scenario where Q2 is on the point of saturation, with \$ V_{CE} = 0.1V\$. The LED has exactly the right current, \$ I_2 = 500mA \$, and exactly the necessary voltage across it to pass that current, \$ V_F = 3.0V\$. Lastly, it just so happens that \$ V_{TOP} = 3.1V\$.

This seems perfect, because with Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL) we see that it all adds up nicely:

$$ V_{TOP} = V_{CE} + V_F = 0.1V + 3.0V = 3.1V $$

This is a terrible situation, though, if anything happens to upset this delicate balance. What would happen if the LED cools down, and the \$ V_F \$ needed for 500mA rises to 3.1V? You need Q2 to be able to *reduce* its \$ V_{CE} \$, leaving a greater "share" of \$ V_{TOP} \$ for the LED, in order to compensate for the changed conditions, and maintain a current of 500mA. But it can't because it's saturated!

For this reason, we must allow some headroom for Q2 to work with. We must make
\$ V_{TOP} \$ significantly greater than \$ V_F \$, so that \$ V_{CE} \$ can begin at, say, 2V, but decrease from there when required.

With that out of the way, maybe we can change your design to produce something that could actually work. Let's start with a really easy "ideal" system, in which we dispense with the wasteful R1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHURlU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where before we asked the mirror to ensure that \$ I_2 = I_3 = 500mA \$, here we merely ask it to balance the currents in the two paths, such that \$ I_1 = I_2 \$. We've set the main current source to 1A, so we can expect each path to carry about 500mA, and there's no conflict.

Also, we've completely lost R1, which was wasting power.

I stated earlier that Q1's collector will be at +0.7V, and we know also that Q2's collector can vary from 0.1V upwards. In a somewhat simplistic and naive sense, it should be clear that if both LEDs are well matched, passing the same 500mA, dropping the same \$ V_F \$, and sharing the same \$ V_{TOP}\$, then Q2's collector will also initially be at +0.7V. But Q2's collector can fall to 0.1V, if necessary, in an attempt to maintain 500mA in its own load. Therefore Q2 does have some "room to manoevure", in that it's \$ V_{CE} \$ is able to vary between 0.1V and 0.7V.

However, we are not yet out of the woods. We are still faced with the possibility that \$ V_F \$ for the two diodes (or worse, the combined "\$ V_F \$"s of entire diode chains) are significantly different. I would like Q2 to have a little extra headroom, to account for such a scenario where the \$ V_F \$ in each path might differ by more than 0.6V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMfThE.png)</sup>

Since I know that the current in R1 will be 500mA, I know by Ohm's law that the voltage across it will be:

$$ V_{R1} = 500mA \times 2\Omega = 1V $$

The current source I1 will comply with this additional 1V requirement, and raise \$ V_{TOP} \$ by 1V. Q2, being a current source in its own right, must also comply, by raising it's own \$ V_{CE} \$ to "consume" that excess of 1V. Otherwise its load's current would increase beyond 500mA. which it must act to prevent.

So now Q2 finds itself with \$ V_{CE} = 1.7V \$, and with freedom to lower that by up to 1.6V if it has to, in order to maintain 500mA in its load.

We still have one more issue to deal with; transistor mismatch. If there's even the slightest variation in characteristics between Q1 and Q2, it will fail to "mirror" accurately. To mitigate this, we can add ballast resistors at their emitters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbh17m.png)</sup>

R2 and R3 tend to equalise the emitter currents that arise from some applied base voltage. They won't completely eradicate differences though. You should take care to use transistors that you have chosen for their similarity, and you should ensure they share the same temperature, by physically joning their cases.

All this should give you some idea of what's going on in these current mirrors, and sources, and provide you with some idea of the problems of and solutions to real-life issues such as LED forward voltage variations and transistor mismatch.

I haven't given any thought to thermal runaway in the LEDs, though. That's a very real problem that should be addressed, especially considering the constant-current aspect to these designs.

Comment: What you said in the last paragraph was the reason I put the transistor with the resistor to 'set' the current. I tested the circuit in your solution and thermal runaway could still occur if the LED in the 'control branch' had a slightly lower forward voltage. I do not like the waste heat generated by having the resistor in the first branch as in the diagram in the question either as it is wasteful as you said. I did think of doing [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/582933/can-current-mirror-branches-be-connected-to-different-sources?noredirect=1#comment1526352_582933).

Comment: Am I correct in saying that setting the supply voltage to VLED + 0.6-0.7V would allow the transistor VCE voltage to vary with VCE varying in order to keep the current at 500mA?

Comment: @MRB Yes. Setting the supply voltage explicitly \$V_{TOP}=V_F+x \$ would effectively give Q2 ability to vary its \$V_{CE}\$ between about 0.1V and \$x\$. So if something happens to change \$V_F\$ (like getting hotter), Q2 has that "headroom" \$x\$ to adjust the voltage across the LED in compensation, to maintain 500mA.

Comment: @MRB The role of R1 is to get that extra headroom. That's the "\$x\$" I speak of.

Comment: Very good answer. I was going to write an answer but I think you covered everything I would have written.

Comment: Maybe 2 Ohms might be on the high side. Maybe 1 Ohm would be enough. Is my only comment.

Comment: @mkeith Your point is important. Perhaps I should have explained that for a single LED in each path, even less than 1Ω would suffice (or no resistance at all; that initial 0.6V headroom is probably enough), but if you had a chain of 10 LEDs, you have a much greater variation in combined \$V_F\$, across the operating temperature range. You'd choose a resistance to drop a voltage somewhat larger than the biggest variation in \$V_F\$ you expect to see.

Comment: I think you did a pretty good job of explaining everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Current distribution in parallel LED strings (3 pages)**

https://www.ee.co.za/wp-content/uploads/legacy/Vector%202013/current%20distribution%20in%20parallel%20led%20strings.pdf

[image]

The current source CC has a compliance voltage range where it can regulate current in this range and stops regulating current outside the compliance. Each LED drops some voltage when driven by a current so the total voltage in each string is approximated by adding up the expected voltage drop across each LED and/or transistor and/or resistor in the series path. So too few or too many series LEDs in each string may take the voltage out of the range for compliance of the constant current source.