# Can current mirror branches be connected to different sources

Tags: transistors, led, current-mirror

Can the branches within a current mirror be connected to different sources as shown below?

[image: I mirror with different sources]

The aim is to provide the high voltage required by each LED but reduce the voltage across the resistor R1 in the branch which sets up the current to reduce the power loss.

Comment: Sure, that's usually the point. Each arm of the current mirror is connected to a different load. The mirror can't tell what's on the other side of that load, as long as it has the correct polarity with respect to the mirror's reference node.

Comment: MRB, So long as all of the sources/sinks have their loads, sure. But if you remove one of them, or one of them fails, then the BJT itself sinks similar current through its base and this will upset the rest of the chain -- without added support, anyway.

Comment: @jonk: Are you sure? I'm trying to think of any mechanism by which the Vbe for a transistor with a "failed" load would go down instead of going up or just staying the same, and I can't come up with anything. What is your reasoning?

Comment: @DaveTweed Imagine Q4, Q5, etc. But one of them doesn't have a collector load. Yet its VBE is being held up just the same. There's no collector current. What happens? (That's where my mind went.)

Comment: Nothing. The same fixed current flows from base to emitter. Physically, some electrons from the emitter may end up in the collector region, but they eventually migrate back to the base region as well. The net flow between base and collector across that depletion region is zero.

Comment: @DaveTweed [Here's a Spice run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Eqm.png). You can see what I mean there. One of the BJTs is operating saturated, not active. Look at the currents for R6 and R7, with the missing R8 gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128898/discussion-between-dave-tweed-and-jonk).